# How to cite a comment to a paper?

Tags: bibliographies

I want to cite a comment to a paper, published in the same issue as the main article. The comment was written by a different author. How can I cite the commentary?

Comment: There are a myriad of ways, but probably only a few make sense in your own documents. Naturally it is hard to guess which would be appropriate because we know *absolutely nothing* about your document.  This is one of many situations where a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) is required in order to get useful answers.

Comment: Are you asking about the mechanics of getting LaTeX (or BibTeX, etc.) to handle this, or about the correct format for such a citation? If the latter, this isn't the right forum for this question.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, and assuming you are asking how to tag it in a bib file, the answer is: handle it as an article.

```
@article{OnMore1617,
  title = {Comments on More's Utopia},
  author = {Erasmus},
  journal = {Classical Review},
  year = 1617
  }
```

Comment: Maybe. It is a style(-guide)-dependent question.  Different disciplines and even different journals in the same discipline handle the question differently.

Comment: @jon I'm thinking about how to manage the bibtex database. I don't know if biblatex allows for another type of entry.

Comment: `Biblatex` does. I imagine some `.bst`s do as well, but I've never looked....